# How do you append a select with a asp-item tag helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a functionality where I append a select html when a button is clicked using jQuery. I already have a select which uses a asp-item tag helper to fill it with my corresponding model. The platform I'm using is asp-net core 2.2 and I'm using a razor page for my page.

My question is how do I edit my jQuery so that when I clicked the button, the asp-item is already loaded into the select?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#AddButton").click(function () {
    tc = tc + 1;
    $("#totalContacts").val(tc)
    $(".addselection").append('<div> <select class="form-control" name="[' + (tc) + '].DriverID" asp-for="TripDrivers.DriverID" asp-items="Model.DriverList" > <option value = ""> Select a driver </option></select></div>')
 });
```

and this is my OnGet to load the items

```
public IActionResult OnGet()
{

    DriverList = _context.Drivers.Select(a =>
                              new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = a.ID.ToString(),
                                  Text = a.FullName
                              }).ToList();
}
```

This is my first ever question, so please bear with me if there are any grammatical errors or missing information. I'll add them if necessary.

EDIT: [Here is the design I'm trying to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsiBS.png)

Once the plus button is clicked. It should add a row of dropdownlist each with the option being loaded from the list on the OnGet method.

ANOTHER EDIT: As per user @itminus instructions, I've created a one sample page and a partial view to apply the code given below.

Here is what my **FirstPage.cshtml** looks like

```
@page
@model MasigasigTrackingSystem.Pages.TestingPages.FirstPageModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>FirstPage</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#AddButton").click(function () {
            tc = tc + 1;
            $("#totalContacts").val(tc)
            $.ajax('?handler=DropdownList', {
                method: "GET",
                data: { tc: tc },
                success: function (d) { $(".addselection").append(d); }
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <button id="AddButton" class="btn" type="button">+</button>
    @*<select asp-for="Mode" asp-items="Model.DropdownListViewModel.Drivers" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select a driver</option>
    </select>*@
    <div class="addselection">
        <partial name="_SecondPage.cshtml" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My **FirstPageModel**

```
namespace MasigasigTrackingSystem.Pages.TestingPages
{
    public class FirstPageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly MasigasigTrackingSystem.Data.ApplicationDBContext _context;

        public FirstPageModel(MasigasigTrackingSystem.Data.ApplicationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Drivers Drivers { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> DriverList { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public DropdownListViewModel DropdownListViewModel { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            DriverList = _context.Drivers.Select(a =>
                              new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = a.ID.ToString(),
                                  Text = a.FullName
                              }).ToList();

            DropdownListViewModel = new DropdownListViewModel();

            DropdownListViewModel.Drivers = DriverList;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGetDropdownListAsync(int tc)
        {
            var list = _context.Drivers.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.ID.ToString(),
                Text = a.FullName,
            }).ToList();  // or filter by Where( ... tc...).ToList()
            return Partial("/Pages/TestingPages/_SecondPage.cshtml", new DropdownListViewModel
            {
                Drivers = list,
                ID = tc,
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My partial **_SecondPage**

```
@using MasigasigTrackingSystem.Models
@model DropdownListViewModel

<div>
    <select class="form-control dropdown" name="[@Model.ID].DriverID" asp-items="@Model.Drivers">
        <option> Select a driver </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My **DropdownlistViewModel**

```
namespace MasigasigTrackingSystem.Models
{
    public class DropdownListViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public IList<SelectListItem> Drivers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: why not render the `<select>` on server before page has been loaded in browser ?

Comment: @itminus is it possible? What I'm trying to do is kinda like a dynamic form where when I could add or remove the dropdown depending on number of items the user needs to input.

Comment: Your original code won't work because the `<select asp-for ... asp-items>` can only be rendered on server side. I'm not sure what you're trying to do. But I think you can use an ajax and return a `select` partial view if you would like to render the `select` dynamically.

Comment: Hi @itminus. I've edited the question above to see if it helps to give you an idea on what I'm trying to accomplish.

If your answer is still the same as before. Is it ok for me to ask for a sample of the ajax code that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I create a demo for your reference. If you have any questions, feel free to update me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a demo that gets the partial view dynamically from server.

1. Create a Handler `OnGetDropdownListAsync(int tc)` in your PageModel:

   ```cs
   public class YourPageModel : PageModel
   {
       ... other handler methods, e.g. OnGet() render the Index

       public IActionResult OnGetDropdownListAsync(int tc)
       {
           var list = _context.Drivers.Select(a =>new SelectListItem{
               Value = a.ID.ToString(),
               Text = a.FullName,
           }).ToList();  // or filter by Where( ... tc...).ToList()
           return Partial( "/Pages/Shared/Selection.cshtml" , new DropdownListViewModel{
               Drivers = list,
               Index = tc,
           });
       }
   }
   ```

   Here the `DropdownListViewModel` is a plain `ViewModel` that holds the data:

   ```cs
   public class DropdownListViewModel{
       public IList<SelectListItem> Drivers{get;set;}
       public int Index {get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. Move your original html snippet within jQuery into a new partial view file: `/Pages/Shared/Selection.cshtml`

   ```
   @using App.Pages
   @model DropdownListViewModel

   <div> 
       <select class="form-control dropdown" name="[@Model.Index].DriverID" asp-items="@Model.Drivers">
           <option> Select a driver </option>
       </select>
   </div>
   ```
3. Finally, change your `JavaScript` to send an ajax request and update the UI in following way:

   ```js
   $("#AddButton").click(function () {
       tc = tc + 1;
       $("#totalContacts").val(tc)
       $.ajax('?handler=DropdownList',{
           method:"GET",
           data:{ tc: tc },
           success:function(d){ $(".addselection").append(d); }
       });
   });
   ```

---

**[Edit]**

1. You are passing currect ViewData to `<partial>` implicitly, which leads to this type error. You need change it to :

   ```
   <partial name="/Pages/TestingPages/_SecondPage.cshtml" model="@Model.DropdownListViewModel" />
   ```
2. You're referencing an slim `jQuery` that doesn't have a `ajax`.  Please change the `script` to `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`.
3. You're binding an event for `#AddButton` before this element has been created. You need wrap the js into a `$(document).ready(function(){  ....  }`. You can also create a manually `script` after the `#AddButton` element.  Or put the `<script>` into `@section Scripts{}` if you're using a default `Layout` which will make the script take effect after the page has been loaded.
4. Also you didn't initialize a `tc` variable.

In short, you need fix the bugs as below:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tc = 0;
        $("#AddButton").click(function () {
            tc = tc + 1;
            $("#totalContacts").val(tc)
            $.ajax('?handler=DropdownList', {
                method: "GET",
                data: { tc: tc },
                success: function (d) { $(".addselection").append(d); }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

...

<div class="addselection">
    <partial name="/Pages/TestingPages/_SecondPage.cshtml" model="@Model.DropdownListViewModel" />
</div
```

Comment: I can't seem to load the data in the partial view for some reason. Do I need to load it in my initial page?

I tried to test this using one blank page and a partial view. Can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @trymode 1. Yes. The partial view should be loaded by ajax in initial page. 2. Actually, I tested my code and I can make sure it works fine for me. If you can't make it, could you please show us the complete code or a project/approach that reproduces the same issue?

Comment: sorry for the late response, but I did a little testing and I'm now getting an error message InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MasigasigTrackingSystem.Pages.TestingPages.FirstPageModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MasigasigTrackingSystem.Models.DropdownListViewModel'. I've edited my question again to post the pages I've done with your code included.

Comment: @trymode It's too long to post my reply as a single comment. Please check my updated answer for how to fix that issue :)

Comment: I think I'm at the finish line already. I'm still getting the same error message but this time it's pointing me to the return Partial in the OnGetDropdownListAsync function, with the error message being the opposite before, it's now trying to require the DropdownListViewModel from the FirstPage. I've already tried removing the model tag  from the partial page, I even removed a new instance of the DropdownListViewModel, still no luck :(

Comment: @trymode Could you please share us the error message and your latest code? According to my test, my code works fine for me.

Comment: @trymode I create a demo online: https://github.com/newbienewbie/SO58532202

Comment: itminus, I've tried your online demo and I'm still getting the error message. Here is the error message that is showing, https://imgur.com/a/3WMBgvH

Comment: @trymode How did you get that error? Did you run my project or create a new project ?

Comment: I get the error whenever I clicked the Add button and yes I did run your online demo. Even did a new project as well. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: I've finally managed to get it work. What I did was create a new instance of the first model while creating a new instance of the DropDownListViewModel, I've also changed the name of the handler from DropdownList to to the class from the partial page. Now the only issue I have is whenever I pressed the add button twice it's doubles the drop down.

Comment: @trymode Could you please elaborate on  "whenever I pressed the add button twice it's doubles the drop down"? I thought it should append a dropdown when you click the `add` button. Shouldn't it?